# Does using a class and dot notation access in Core Data get a mutable set?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an entity called `LogBook` which has an attribute (called `columns`) for a set of `LogBookColumn` entities (one-to-many relationship).

The standard way I see to retrieve the mutable set of columns seems to be:

```
NSEntityDescription *myLogbook;
myLogbook = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LogBook"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSMutableSet *columns = [myLogbook mutableSetValueForKey:@"columns"];
```

Instead of method on the third line, I want to use dot notation.  To do so, I have created class definitions, also called `LogBook` and `LogBookColumn`, and use @property to create the setters and getters.

```
LogBook *myLogBook;
myLogbook = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LogBook"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSMutableSet *columns = (NSMutableSet *)myLogbook.columns;
```

So, is `columns` truly a mutable set by default?  I have done two things to verify:

- Attempted to write to the list, eg: `[columns addObject:aColumn];`
- Asked with: `BOOL isKindOfMutableSet = [myLogbook.columns isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]];`

Both work with expected results, which may make this question overkill, but I am very concerned about memory errors that will be difficult to track down.  I also wonder if asking the question `isKindOfClass` will work as I have defined this as a mutable set - so won't it work even if the underlying memory organization doesn't support mutable sets?

All of the above sums up to: is this the right way to access and change the `columns` property/attribute?

Comment: What is the datatype of `columns` in `LogBook`?

Comment: `LogBookColumn`, which is another entity.  Oddly enough, the code doesn't need to know that in either case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW7), to-many relationships should be declared as `NSSet`, which makes sense. Even if the attribute returns an `NSMutableSet`, it is not guaranteed that updating the `NSMutableSet` will properly update relationships ([which `mutableSetValueForKey:` does](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW6)).

If you really want a mutable accessor, then just create a `readonly` property that wraps `mutableSetValueForKey:`

**Update:**

Otherwise, we are supposed to use - (void)addLogBookColumnsObject:(LogBookColumn *)value;, - (void)removeLogBookColumnsObject:(LogBookColumn *)value;, - (void)addLogBookColumns:(NSSet *)values;, - (void)removeLogBookColumns:(NSSet *)values; that were generated by Core Data for us.

Comment: Hmm.  I saw that too, and have declared it as `NSSet` in my .h.  However, that makes little sense to me - why on earth would we have dot accessors that don't work and require wraping in a custom property not created by XCode?  Don't get me wrong, I realize this must be the case - I just hope it isn't...which is why I will wait and see if any other answers show up.

Comment: Because we are supposed to use `- (void)addLogBookColumnsObject:(LogBookColumn *)value;`, `- (void)removeLogBookColumnsObject:(LogBookColumn *)value;`, `- (void)addLogBookColumns:(NSSet *)values;`, `- (void)removeLogBookColumns:(NSSet *)values;` that were generated by Core Data for us.

Comment: Wow.  Of course.  I think that's the right answer.  Want to put it up there so I can mark it?